# Javascript random integer button

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to make a button that when clicked outputs an integer from 1-11. I have tested the "getRandomInt" function and it works, however when I try to add the button aspect nothing comes up when I click the button. Also the console does not log any errors.
code:

```
<form>
<input type="button" onclick="getRandomInt()" value="Click Here">
<br>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};
document.write(getRandomInt(1, 12));

</script>
```

Can someone explain it in layman's terms how to fix this because the function should be correct, I think the button is wrong somehow and I think the two aren't being connected properly.

Comment: You're not passing parameters on your input

Comment: It would be like this : `<input type="button" onclick="getRandomInt(1, 12)" value="Click Here">`

Comment: Also, there is no visible output of just calling the function. You'd need to console.log or alert the result or something.

Comment: How exactly do you want the button to "output" the number?

Comment: Pretty similar issue with solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752100/trying-to-get-a-random-number-on-button-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply arguments to `getRandomInt` when you call it. You also need to wrap the function call in something like `document.write` so you can see the output

```
<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="document.write(getRandomInt(1, 10))" value="Click Here">
    <br>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
};
document.write(getRandomInt(1, 12));

</script>
```

Comment: I tried that before posting here and it didn't work.

Comment: @user6428243 I updated my answer to include wrapping getRandomInt in a document.write call. Try that

Comment: @melpomene You're right. I updated my answer to include wrapping getRandomInt in a document.write call

Comment: @user6428243 don't hesitate to accept an answer that works for you by clicking the green checkmark

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the glue between your program logic (`getRandomInt()`) and the presentation (`document.write()`), i. e. later statement is not part of your button's event handler.

I'd like to propose the following solution which [avoids calling document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) and instead sets the text property of a dedicated `<span id='display-random'>`:

```js
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var button = document.getElementById('button-random'),
    display = document.getElementById('display-random');

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  display.textContent = getRandomInt(1, 12);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="button" id="button-random" value="Click Here">
</form>
<span id="display-random"></span>
```